# How do I remove white-space from the beginning of a string?

Tags: java, whitespace, trim

How do I remove white-space from the beginning of a string in Java without removing from the end?

If the value is:

```
String temp = "    hi    "
```

Then how can I delete only the leading white-space so it looks like this:

```
String temp = "hi    "
```

The current implementation I have is to loop through, checking the first character and creating a substring until the first non-whitespace value is reached.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use:

```
temp = temp.replaceFirst("^\\s*", "")
```

Comment: This won't work with strings that already don't have whitespace. It should be `temp.replaceFirst("^\\s*", "");` so that `^` matches the beginning of the string.

Comment: The OP would also need to make sure the String starts with whitespace characters.

Comment: The `^` is only needed when using `String.replaceAll`. While it will work fine here, it is not needed for `String.replaceFirst`

Answer (score 9):

You could use Commons-lang StringUtils [stripStart](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripStart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

If you pass null it will automatically trim the spaces.

```
StringUtils.stripStart(temp, null);
```

Answer (score 6):

As of `JDK11` you can use [stripLeading](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripLeading()):

```
String result = temp.stripLeading();
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably close to the implementation of the suggested Commons-lang StringUtils.stripStart() method:

```
public static String trimFront(String input) {
    if (input == null) return input;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(i)))
            return input.substring(i);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blatantly copied from [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Removeleadingwhitespacefromastring.htm):

```
text = text.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

...and modified using `@Reimus`'s answer:

```
text = text.replaceFirst("^\\s+", "");
```

I'm not sure of the most efficient method; fwiw, I went with `@Reimus`'s original.