# When splitting around whitespace (\s+) the first index of the first resulting string has an empty 0th char

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm completely baffled. When running `line.split("\\s+")` on the first line from a file, the first value in the array has an empty char.

After my equals tests kept failing, I started up my debugger and the first char of the first char of the word in the file is empty (not a space, but empty).

[image: The highlighted row is the empty char.]

Any explanations on how this is happening, plus a solution would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754582/how-do-i-remove-white-space-from-the-beginning-of-a-string

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: There is possibly some non-printable whitespace character in your file.

Comment: There is nothing like an "empty char". It is most probably some whitespace char.

Comment: @FabianBarney, zero-width is kind of like empty ;)

Comment: Well, it's some kind of invisibility but not emptyness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to copy the contents of the first character and look at the hex code to figure out what was going on.

The value was a `ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE (U+FEFF)`. Since Java's trim() only defines whitespace as ["anything up to and including U+0020 (the usual space character) as whitespace"](http://closingbraces.net/2008/11/11/javastringtrim/), this character was not caught.

I ended up adding a special case for this character in my code.

Comment: +1 for finding the invisible character and let us know which one it was :)

Answer (score 0):

remove leading/trailing spaces first.

```
line = line.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the first entry for the array if it ALWAYS gives you that result. You could perform a test if position 0 is null or "" or whatever that value is.

Then turn it into a static function and out of sight, out of mind.

Comment: A `char` is primitive. So value at `char[0]` cannot be `null` and cannot be an empty `String` (incompatible type). It is most probably some whitespace char.

Comment: Pardon, I am not THAT familiar with Java. If its a char, then '' ?

Comment: `''` is simply invalid. `char c = ''` would not compile. There is nothing like an empty char. `char c = null` would not compile, because `char` is primitive. That's why it must be some (invisible) character here in question.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like an "empty char".

Whitespace is defined as: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` [Pattern Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

So your character at position 0 is most probably an invisible character that is not part of the "whitespace" set above.

You may want to pass the character in question to [Character.getNumericValue(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) and look into a unicode codepoint table to know what character it is.